# About using find with prune option

Tags: find

I have a source folder where you can find files with extensions `.c`, `.pc`, `.pro.c`.

I want to find all files with `.c` and `.pc` only, since `.pro.c` is a generated file from `.pc` after preprocessing.

Here is my find expression which is not yet correct:

```
find source \( \( -name '*.pro.c' \) -a -prune \) -o \( -name '*.c' -a -print \)
```

What is my mistake ?

Can someone help me and explain why I do not get the correct result ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think there's a mistake? Please [provide a small example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/600201/edit) set of files, [show](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/600201/edit) what your `find` collects, and [show](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/600201/edit) what you want it to collect. Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to get ```.pc``` file names if you don’t ask for them?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put brackets around `-name '*.pro.c'`. Those are a test and its value. No way those are torn apart by any precedence.

Comment: `-prune` is for directories. If you want to exclude certain test results, just negate them: `! -name '*.pro.c' -name '*.c'`. No need for `-print` either, that is done automatically.

Answer (score 4):

`-prune` applies to directories, not files, and instructs `find` not to descend into the directory it’s looking at.

You only need to negate a name test:

```
find source -name '*.c' ! -name '*.pro.c' -o -name '*.pc'
```

Comment: @DominiqueCrétel If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others who have a similar problem may find it more easily.